# Video doesn't play in any of Iphone's browsers and gets over text when it loads, How can I wait for everything to load and then render my site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm creating my personal site with Gatsby. I want to have a video background for the first section. On my desktop browsers works, the video takes time to load but when it does it is in the right place (is there a way to wait for everything my site needs to load and then render it ?). In my phone (iPhone X) it doesn't seem to work for any browser (chrome, firefox, safari). The video takes longer to load and when it does it get's over the text.

I am actually clueless about how to solve this issue. This is the link to my site: https://davidneios.netlify.com/en/

And the repository: https://github.com/DavidNeiOs/davidneios_www

you can find the full file in davidneios_www/src/pages/index.tsx

```js
 const IndexPage = ({ intl }: Props) => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <VideoWrapper>
      <MainVideo muted loop id="myVideo" autoPlay playsinline>
        <source src={CityMp4} type="video/mp4" />
        <source src={CityWeb} type="video/webm" />
      </MainVideo>
      <VideoInfo>
        <Text withComponent="h1" variant="headerLargePrimarydBold">
          {intl.formatMessage({ id: "index.h1.title" })}
        </Text>
        <Text variant="bodyLargePrimary">Born and raised in Colombia </Text>
        <Text variant="bodyLargePrimary">
          I have been living in Montreal, CA for almost 4 years
        </Text>
      </VideoInfo>
    </VideoWrapper>
  </Layout>
)

export default injectIntl(IndexPage)
```

I'm just expecting the video to work the same as it does in desktop browsers. I haven't tested in android browsers but I am guessing it would have a similar problem

Comment: The `playsinline` and `muted` attribute are set in the above code but not on your netlify version...

Comment: @ksav you are right, I found that's a problem with react itself and the only for now is to use `dangerouslysetinnerhtml` which is not what I need at the moment